# jQuery Change Value of Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a product table.
I have a button on every row. When I click on button I want to change value of input textbox by add 1 just for this row. But its work just for first row. 
My HTML and jQuery codes below.
Please help me.

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="column">A Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button onclick="$.updatequantity();">+</button></p>
    <p class="column" id="price">55 TL</p>
    <p class="column" id="total">275 TL</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <p class="column">Another Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button onclick="$.updatequantity();">+</button></p>
    <p class="column" id="price">25 TL</p>
    <p class="column" id="total">125 TL</p>
</div>



<script>
$.updatequantity = function(){
        var i=+$("#quantity").val();
        i +=1;
        $("#quantity").val(i);
        var price = $("#price").text();
        var result = price.replace(' TL','');
        var total = result * i;
        $("#total").html(total).show();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: id attribute should be unique. Note you got "quantity" twice

Comment: ok. we suppose that the id is unique. How can i get this id value dynamically with jquery?

Comment: You don't have to use id, I'm working on a fiddle for you - give me a min

Comment: my answer below, as I promise.. feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you use an onclick listener. Here is an live example

```js
$(".incre").on("click", function() {
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find("#quantity");
    
    var i=+ quantity.val();
    i +=1;
    quantity.val(i);
    var price = $(this).parent().parent().find("#price").text();
    var result = price.replace(' TL','');
    var total = result * i;
    $(this).parent().parent().find("#total").html(total).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <p class="column">A Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button class="incre">+</button></p>
    <p class="column" id="price">55 TL</p>
    <p class="column" id="total">275 TL</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <p class="column">Another Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button class="incre">+</button></p>
    <p class="column" id="price">25 TL</p>
    <p class="column" id="total">125 TL</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, just keep in mind that it is better to avoid same id in the same html

Answer (score 1):

If you give each row a unique id and pass that id (as a string of course) to the onclick's invocation, then it should work as you expect. The new update function would look like this:

```
$.updatequantity = function(row_selector){
    var i= +$(row_selector).find('input').val();
    i +=1;
    $(row_selector).find('input').val(i);
    var price = $(row_selector).find('#price').text();
    var result = price.replace(' TL','');
    var total = result * i;
    $(row_selector).find('#total').html(total).show();
}
```

It should also work with 'this' references, but I'm a little rustier at that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1au4Lv64/)

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="column">A Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button>+</button></p>
    <p class="column price">55 TL</p>
    <p class="column total">275 TL</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <p class="column">Another Product Name</p>
    <p class="column"><input type="text" size=1 id="quantity" value="5"/> <button>+</button></p>
    <p class="column price">25 TL</p>
    <p class="column total">125 TL</p>
</div>

$("button").click(function(event){
        var i=+$(event.target).prev().val()
        i +=1;
        $(event.target).prev().val(i);
        var price = $(event.target).parent().next().text();
        var result = price.replace(' TL','');
        var total = result * i;
        $(event.target).parent().next().next().html(total).show();
  });
```